# Make chapter numbers appear in ToC (documentclass: book, using biblatex) and modification of the format of the Reference chapter

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, cross-referencing

I’m using biblatex and I have made each chapter in separate tex file, and I combine them on the main.tex
Each chapter is showing with number.name, which is as I want, as you can see from the picture 1 below:
[image]
However, it doesn’t show the word “References”, as it supposed to do, as you can see from the picture 2 below:
[image]
But as you can see the references are there:

[image]

At first, I don’t know why the references do not showing in the table of contents.
As a second, I want the title of the references to be as chapter like as the other chapters i.e.,  “16. References”.
I would like to know how I can fix them.

The source code on the main file is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,oneside,12pt,lot, lof]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}
\usepackage{substitutefont}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\newcommand{\imp}[1]{\underline{\textit{#1}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\graphicspath{ {images/} } 
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{epigraph} 
\usepackage{parskip}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot,numbib]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[bibstyle=numeric, citestyle=numeric, natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refzotero2.bib}
\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{fvextra, csquotes}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{emptypage}  
\usepackage{lipsum}     
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  
\newcommand\blankpage{
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty} %------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \addtocounter{page}{1}
    \newpage}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% DEFINITIONS ----------------------------------------------
\def\AA{\mathring{\mathrm{A}}}
\def\rcurs{{\mbox{$\resizebox{.16in}{.08in}{\includegraphics{ScriptR}}$}}}
\def\brcurs{{\mbox{$\resizebox{.16in}{.08in}{\includegraphics{BoldR}}$}}}
\def\hrcurs{{\mbox{$\hat \brcurs$}}}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{c1}{rgb}{0,0,1} % blue
\definecolor{c2}{rgb}{0,0.3,0.9} % light blue
\definecolor{c3}{rgb}{0.3,0,0.9} % red blue
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
   
%% HYPERLINKS%
\usepackage[
    colorlinks=true
    ,breaklinks
    ]{hyperref} 
 \urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{url}  
\urlstyle{helvet}  
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue, filecolor=magenta, urlcolor=cyan,}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true, 
  urlcolor=blue,   
  linkcolor=blue, 
  citecolor=blue  
}
\hypersetup{
    linkcolor={c1},
    citecolor={c2},
    urlcolor={c3} 
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsbsy, amsmath, amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}    
\usepackage{bm}         
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand\vn[1]{^{}_{\mathrm{#1}}} 
\newcommand{\spr}[1]{\ensuremath{^\textrm{#1}}}
\newcommand{\sub}[1]{\ensuremath{_\textrm{#1}}}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  range-units=single,
  separate-uncertainty=true,
  multi-part-units=single
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigdelim} 
\usepackage{bigstrut} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{dirtytalk} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\let\cleardoublepage\clearemptydoublepage  
\let\cleardoublepage=\clearpage %\afterpage{\blankpage}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\input{settings/page}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{left=2.20cm,right=1.0cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,includehead,includefoot,headheight=16pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\cfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\singlespacing
\setstretch{1.5}
\usepackage{mieUTHtitle-en}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{chngcntr}
 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\captionsetup{labelfont=bf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[rightcaption]{sidecap}
\usepackage{lastpage}                  
\usepackage{emptypage}
\parindent=0cm 
\sloppy 
\hyphenation{} 
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\exhyphenpenalty=10000
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title{RF Circuit \& System Design Project Report }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\maketitle
\frontmatter
\pagestyle{plain}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
\chapter*{Abstract}
\input{prelim/abstract}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{plain}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\stepcounter{tocdepth} %include subsections in TOC
\tableofcontents
%\newpage
\listoffigures
\listoftables
%\pagestyle{plain}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pagestyle{plain}
\mainmatter 
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatother
\include{ch1}
\include{ch2}
\include{ch3}
\include{ch4}
\include{ch5}
\include{ch6}
\include{ch7}
\include{ch8}
\include{ch9}
\include{ch10}
\include{ch11}
\include{ch12}
\include{ch13}
\include{ch14}
\include{ch15}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\clearpage
\cleardoublepage
   \phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\refname}
\printbibliography[title=References]
\clearpage
\cleardoublepage
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\include{ch17}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
```

Any ideas, recommendations, or suggestions are more than welcome.